# Sonar Upgrade Fail from 3.0 to 3.7

Tags: oracle, jdbc, odbc, sonarqube

While I was trying to upgrade Sonar from version 3.0 to 3.7 I get the following error:

> org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
>
> #### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400:
>
> EinfÃ¼gen von NULL in ("SONAR"."RESOURCE_INDEX"."ID") nicht mÃ¶glich

I am using a Oracle 11g database, Oracle Database 11g Release 1 (11.1.0.7.0) JDBC Driver and Java 1.6.0_45.

Comment: Could you provide your full SonarQube server log or at least several lines before and after this error ?

Comment: @FreddyMallet-SonarSource You can find the full log under http://www.xup.in/dl,10058539/sonar.txt/

Answer (score 2):

FYI, JIRA ticket created to track this bug : http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4608

Answer (score 0):

I think I know whats going on here:
The occuring error was previously fixed with Sonar 3.6.2.
(http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4503)

I sucessfully installed Sonar 3.6.2 and 3.6.3.
So in my opinion the above noticed bug made a return in Sonar 3.7.

Comment: Be patient, we're currently investigating this issue which seems to relate to http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4178

Comment: Note that the provided logs show that it's not an upgrade from 3.0, but from a 2.x version (2.7 ?). Do you confirm ?

Comment: The provided log shows an upgrade from 2.6, as i made a complete rollback after the failure of upgrading from 3.0 .